# Rewrite url after rewritten

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have URL: /home.php?id=fun and I rewrote to: /fun.html use:

> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$ home.php?id=$1

In this page I have submit: frdate=2017-08-20 and todate=2017-08-26

It becomes: /fun.html?frdate=2017-08-20&todate=2017-08-26

How to get the $ _GET ['frdate'] and $ _GET ['todate'] trong /fun.html (/home.php?id=fun) form that URL?

Comment: Just add a QSA flag at the end of the rule **[QSA]** this will combine your new querystring with the old one.

Comment: Oh, can you write detail help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default ,Mod-rewrite discards new querystring if your  destination path already contains a querystring. To combine both new and old querystrings, you need to use QSA (Query String Append ) flag.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$ home.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```